# Prove the inequality $ax+by+cz+\sqrt{\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)}\ge\frac23(a+b+c)(x+y+z)$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, radicals, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Prove the inequality
> $$ax+by+cz+\sqrt{\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)}\ge\frac23(a+b+c)(x+y+z)$$
> $a,b,c,x,y,z \in \mathbb R$

#### My attempts:

$$ax+by+cz+\sqrt{\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)}\ge\frac23(a+b+c)(x+y+z)$$

$$(a+x-b-y)^2+(c+z-a-x)^2+(b+y-c-z)^2+(a+b+c-x-y-z)^2 \ge \\ \ge 3 \left( \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \right)^2$$ Let $a-x=A, \:b-y=B, \:c-z=C,\:a+x=X, \:b+y=Y, \:c+z=Z$. Then
$$(X-Y)^2+(X-Z)^2+(Y-Z)^2+(A+B+C)^2 \ge \\ \ge \frac{3}{4} \left( \sqrt{(A+X)^2+(B+Y)^2+(C+Z)^2}-\sqrt{(A-X)^2+(B-Y)^2+(C-Z)^2} \right)^2$$

Comment: What's the source for the inequality? Does it have a motivation or application?

Comment: @CarlMummert I was able to relate it to transmission of light between not necessarily aligned polarizing filters because the $n$-d case always reduces to the $2$-d case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you had two vectors on the unit sphere $\hat u=\langle0,0,1\rangle$ and $\hat v\langle\sin\psi,0,\cos\psi\rangle$. $0\le\psi\le\pi$ and you wanted to find the vector $\hat w=\langle\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta\rangle$ such that $(\hat w\cdot\hat u)(\hat w\cdot\hat v)$ is maximized.
Then we want to maximize
$$(\sin\theta\cos\phi\sin\psi+\cos\theta\cos\psi)\cos\theta=\frac12\cos\phi\sin\psi\sin2\theta+\frac12\cos\psi(1+\cos2\theta)$$
If $\sin2\theta<0$ we want $\cos\phi=-1$ whereas if $\sin2\theta>0$, $\cos\phi=1$. In either case $(\hat w\cdot\hat u)(\hat w\cdot\hat v)=\frac12\cos\psi+\frac12\cos(2\theta\pm\psi)$ which has a maximum of
$$\frac12(1+\cos\psi)=\cos^2\frac{\psi}2$$
By rotations we could have started out with any $2$ unit vectors $\hat u$ and $\hat v$ and found that
$$(\hat w\cdot\hat u)(\hat w\cdot\hat v)\le\frac12(1+\hat u\cdot\hat v)$$
Here our
$$\begin{align}\hat u&=\frac{\langle a,b,c\rangle}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\\
\hat v&=\frac{\langle x,y,z\rangle}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\\
\hat w&=\frac{\langle1,1,1\rangle}{\sqrt{3}}\end{align}$$
So we have
$$\frac{(a+b+c)(x+y+z)}{3\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\le\frac12\left(1+\frac{ax+by+cz}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right)$$
Which works out to
$$\frac23(a+b+c)(x+y+z)\le\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}+ax+by+cz$$
I feel kinda bad about the first part of my proof, though: shouldn't there be a more elegant way to show that the unit vector $\hat w$ has to lie halfway between $\hat u$ and $\hat v$?

**EDIT**: I felt so bad about the first part of my proof that I wanted to show how it could be done cleaner. Again, given $2$ unit vectors $\hat u$ and $\hat v$ we are trying to find the unit vector $\hat w$ that maximizes $\left(\hat w\cdot\hat u\right)\cdot\left(\hat w\cdot\hat v\right)$. We decompose $\hat w$ into its components parallel and perpendicular to the plane containing $\hat u$ and $\hat v$:
$$\hat w=\vec w_{\parallel}+\vec w_{\bot}$$
Then
$$1=\|\hat w\|^2=\|\vec w_{\parallel}\|^2+2\vec w_{\parallel}\cdot\vec w_{\bot}+\|\vec w_{\bot}\|^2=\|\vec w_{\parallel}\|^2+\|\vec w_{\bot}\|^2$$
So $\|\vec w_{\parallel}\|^2\le1$. Then assuming we can attain a positive value of our objective function
$$\left(\hat w\cdot\hat u\right)\cdot\left(\hat w\cdot\hat v\right)=\left(\vec w_{\parallel}\cdot\hat u\right)\cdot\left(\vec w_{\parallel}\cdot\hat v\right)\le\frac{\left(\vec w_{\parallel}\cdot\hat u\right)\cdot\left(\vec w_{\parallel}\cdot\hat v\right)}{\|\vec w_{\parallel}\|^2}$$
So the maximum is attained only for a unit vector $\hat w$ lying in the plane containing $\hat u$ and $\hat v$. This reduces to a $2$-dimensional problem. Let $\hat w\cdot\hat u=\cos\alpha$, $\hat w\cdot\hat v=\cos\xi$, and $\hat u\cdot\hat v=\cos\psi$. Then
$$\begin{align}\left(\hat w\cdot\hat u\right)\cdot\left(\hat w\cdot\hat v\right)&=\cos\alpha\cos\xi=\frac12\left(\cos(\alpha+\xi)+\cos(\alpha-\xi)\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\cos\psi+\cos(\alpha-\xi)\right)\le\frac12\left(\cos\psi+1\right)\end{align}$$
This is familiar from optics where if you have light passing through $2$ plane polarizing filters at angle $\psi$ between them you get maximum transmission when a third such filter at angle $\frac{\psi}2$ is placed between them so the transmission coefficient through the last $2$ filters becomes $\cos^4\frac{\psi}2=\frac14(1+\cos\psi)^2$.

Well, that might have seemed more long-winded than my previous proof and it was, but the cool thing about it is that no reference was made to spherical coordinates so now we can let
$$\begin{align}\hat u=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i\hat e_i}{\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i^2}},&&
\hat v=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i\hat e_i}{\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i^2}},&&
\hat w=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\hat e_i}{\sqrt n}\end{align}$$
And this will work out to
$$\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i+\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i^2}\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i^2}\ge\frac2n\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)$$
Valid for $n\ge1$.

Answer (score 2):

By C-S $$ax+by+cz+\sqrt{\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)}=$$
$$=ax+by+cz+\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)\left(9(x^2+y^2+z^2)\right)}=$$
$$=ax+by+cz+\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)\sum_{cyc}(2y+2z-x)^2}\geq$$
$$=ax+by+cz+\frac{1}{3}(a(2y+2z-x)+b(2x+2z-y)+c(2x+2y-z))=$$
$$=ax+by+cz+\tfrac{1}{3}(a(2y+2z+2x-3x)+b(2x+2z+2y-3y)+c(2x+2y+2z-3z))=$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}(a+b+c)(x+y+z).$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Since we know that $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2 \ge 0 \implies$
$a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge ab + bc + ac$. Multiplying both sides by 2, we get: $$2(a^2+b^2+c^2) \ge 2(ab + bc + ac)$$
Summing both sides by $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$, we get:
$$2(a^2+b^2+c^2) + a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \ge 2(ab + bc + ac) + a^2 + b^2 + c^2$$
$$\implies 3(a^2+b^2+c^2) \ge (a+b+c)^2$$
$$\implies \sqrt{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)} \ge a + b +c$$
Therefore for $x,y$ and $z$, we get:
$$\sqrt{3(x^2+y^2+z^2)} \ge x + y +z$$
Multiplying both sides $(1)$:
$$3\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)} \ge (a+b+c)(x+y+z)$$
$$\implies 2\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)} \ge \frac{2}{3}(a+b+c)(x+y+z)$$
Since we know that $\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)} \ge ax+by+cz$. Therefore $(2)$:
$$3\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)} \ge \frac{2}{3}(a+b+c)(x+y+z)+ax+by+cz$$
Substracting $(1)-(2)$:
$$\implies ax + by +cz \ge \frac{1}{3}(a+b+c)(x+y+z)$$
Therefore:
$$\frac{1}{3}(a+b+c)(x+y+z)+\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)} \ge \frac{2}{3}(a+b+c)(x+y+z)$$
$$\implies ax + by +cz + \sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)} \ge \frac{2}{3}(a+b+c)(x+y+z)$$

Comment: I think your last step is wrong.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg From the first equation: $(a y - b x)^2 + (a z - c x)^2 + (b z - c y)^2 \ge 0$. Therefore $\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)}\ge ax+by+cz$

Comment: Yes, but how you got the last inequality in your post? Explain it please.

Comment: You proved that $3\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)}\geq ax+by+cz+\frac{2}{3}(a+b+c)(x+y+z)$. I think it's not exactly which we need to prove.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg Thank you for pointing this out !